# transaction fail after calling transfer to the contract itself

Tags: solidity, erc-20, transfer, msg.sender

I have this line in some function in an ERC721 contract:

```
IERC20 instance = IERC20(token_address);
instance.transfer(address(this),1);
```

And when deploying the contract I make sure the caller of the function gets at least one of those ERC20 tokens:

```js
ERC20Token[-1].mint(account2,1,{"from":account1})
```

Before deploying the ERC721 contract and calling this specific function with `account2`.

The error I get is:

```
"Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted: ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually."
```

After approving the ERC721 contract to spend some ERC20 from `account2` it works.

When approving inside this specific question it doesn't work..

```
(instance.approve(address(this),1))
```

the `msg.sender` is `account2`.. What is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `transfer` function in ERC20 is for transferring tokens from the current contract address to some other account, so your line of code is trying to transfer 1 unit of the token from the contract to itself.

What you are most likely looking for is `transferFrom(sender, recipient, amount)` which is a more general form of `transfer`, allowing your contract to send tokens from accounts that have approved your contract to do so.

In your example, it would be:

```
IERC20 instance = IERC20(token_address);
instance.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), 1);
```

You will not be able to call `approve` on behalf of other users from your contract, though - this will always be something the user has to do before interacting with your contract.

Comment: The point is that im trying to send the token from the msg.sender to the contract itself.  As i understand it is that the msg sender is the one who calls the function, so the transfer function should transfer one token from account2 to the ERC721 contract. I also tried the transferFrom function and gets :"Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted: ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually."

Comment: Yes, I understand the intention, and that is what `transferFrom` is for. Does `account2` have any of the tokens, and has it approved your contract to spend any of it?

Comment: when im approving the contract to spend from account2,it works.. but why? the msg.sender is account2 ..

Comment: Because the contract is spending tokens on behalf of `account2`. Contracts can't just spend tokens as they wish, they can only spend what users approve them to spend - otherwise any contract could just take your tokens from you, even if you didn't know you interacted with the contract in the first place :)

Comment: I thought that account2 is the caller of the transferFrom inside this specific function because he is the caller of the function, the actual caller is the contract?

Comment: No, `msg.sender` is the sender of the most immediate call. So, from the perspective of the token, `msg.sender` is your contract. `msg.sender` is not necessarily the sender of the original transaction.